# SSL/TLS Configuration on server

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, centos7, x509

I am working on CentOS 7. I have three blocks in text :

```
CSR:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

Public key:
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Private key:
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Also, I have archieve with:

```
mydomain.crt 
mydomain.ca-bundle
```

and

```
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
```

As I understand I need to convert CSR,Private Key, Public Key to right format files ?

Than, add : 
CSR and Private Key to /etc/nginx.conf

And set it via .conf by names ?

But could anyone help me convert CSR,Private Key and Public Key to right formats ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can discard the CSR or keep it for your reference. A CSR (Certificate Signing Request) is a document asking for a certificate, you already have the certificate, so the request is now only of historical interest.

You should put the private key text, including that header and footer, but no blank lines, into a file, let's call that privkey.pem. The private key is very important, you web server software needs to be able to read it in order to function, but nobody else should ever see this file and you should not keep copies of it where they may be stolen.

You also need the mydomain.crt file, and the mydomain.ca-bundle, you should concatenate them together, you can do this (carefully) with a text editor and save the result as fullchain.pem, or if you're comfortable on a Unix command line you can write

```
cat mydomain.crt mydomain.ca-bundle > fullchain.pem
```

In your nginx.conf you should find or create a server block, and set parameters as follows, but with the correct full path names.

```
ssl_certificate /full/path/to/fullchain.pem
ssl_certificate_key /full/path/to/privkey.pem
```